# Climate modelling: statistical downscaling or dynamical?

Tags: climate-change, climate, climate-models

I would like to assess climate change impacts on Protected Areas (e.g. natural reserves, national parks) for Mediterranean countries. I found easily future data from several Global Circulation Models with high resolution (using statistical downscaling), for instance on WorldClim (http://www.worldclim.org/version1), which is highly used in ecology.

But I just realized that I also could use dynamical downscaling of these models (i.e. Regional Circulation Models), as I am focusing on a specific region. However it also looks like the resolution of these RCM is not much better than the resolution of GCM and that it would be necessary to download outputs from many areas (in order to cover the entire Mediterranean region). Moreover, it also seems to be much more difficult (for an ecologist) to find and download these files.

Is there any interest, at my scale, in using RCM rather than GCM with statistical downscaling?

Thank you